# CodeIgniter GET method and SEO friendly URLs

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my web page search input I am using the **get** method, and the URL is something like this `www.example.com/search?city=example&service=example2`, but I want a URL like this `www.example.com/search/example/example2`; how can I convert?

Or maybe there is some other solution to get the data from html inputs and get a friendly URL?

Comment: Look at this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: GET from where ?? form submit or `<a>` ??

Comment: You cant then. And with from submit you cant do any SEO friendly thing. use AJAX or post. NO SEO works on this

Comment: I dont care what way i will use submit or other, i just need get data from the inputs after user clicked search button and it will do a redirect to my controller with my paramaters from input.

Comment: Do you know jquery ajax? I'll post sollution

Comment: Yes i know little bit.

Comment: I have improved the english (spelling, capitalisation, etc) of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think its help you and also SEO.
Please write following uri rules in : `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['search-(:any)-(:any).html'] = 'search?city=$1&service=$2';
```

its rewrite your url from `www.example.com/search?city=example&service=example2`  to `www.example.com/search-example-example2.html`

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.php file inside the config folder:

```html
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/searchFunction'; //You will now need to have a searchFunction() inside the controller search. Or you can just have 'search' and handle the code below inside the index() function.
```

Now, inside your searchFunction:

```js
function searchFunction()
{
  $city = (isset($this->uri->segment(2))) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : null; //if you have www.example.com/search/example
  
  $service = (isset($this->uri->segment(3))) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : null; //if you have www.example.com/search/example/example2
  
//General Pattern is: www.example.com/uri-segment-1/uri-segment-2/uri-segment-3.....and so on.

  // Now when you are querying, if($city) then 'WHERE city = $city' and so on.
  
  //Also, in the link that was earlier triggering 'www.example.com/search?city=example&service=example2'
  //like <a href='www.example.com/search?city=example&service=example2'>Link</a>
  //Now have it as:
  // <a href='www.example.com/search/example/example2'>Link</a>
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see others posting about routing, yes i can do like what, but i think first i need to solve problem with html submit action, because when i press the button its auto redirect to what standart format url `search?city=example&service=example2`, but like i say i need other format. So how i can solve this problem?

My form action

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/search">
```